# Which editor can I use to create a nested hierarchy?

Tags: text-editors, text-editing, openoffice-writer

I'm using OpenOffice (don't have Microsoft Office).  I'm designing an application and I want to create a hierarchy similar to what the image below shows.

[image]

There can be several nested levels of hierarchy and I should be able to create another by simply pressing `Tab` or undoing it by `Shift-Tab`.

**Which tool/editor can I use for it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose styles in `Menu` -> `Format` -> `Bullets and Numbering`

I'm using LibreOffice, should be same as OpenOffice.

and [HERE](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Numbered_bulleted_lists) is the help document.